# Printing only one Key from a Dictionary using loop

Tags: python

Ive been working on this python assignment in school and was stucked at this particular question given to me. From the data given, I would want to find out the person with the most savings.

```
data = {
'Brad':5000, 
'Greg':8000, 
'Sarah':9000000, 
'Kim':6500000, 
'George':24000, 
'Ben':1000
  }
```

My code:

```
most_savings = 0

for person, savings in data.items():
    if savings > most_savings:
        most_savings = savings
        print(person,"has the most savings at",savings)
```

printed output was:

```
Brad has the most savings at 5000
Sarah has the most savings at 9000000
```

desired output:

```
Sarah has the most savings at 9000000
```

Im not getting my desired output. I would like to know where did i go wrong. Need some help here. Thanks

Comment: The question is, do you want to output something as soon as you find a person whose income is greater than that of _some_ other person? Or do you want to output only when you're sure that person's income is _the biggest_?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dont print in a loop - you will print the "at this time" richest one.

```
most_savings = 0
pers = None 

# process all data, remembers pers and most_savings    
for person, savings in data.items():
    if savings > most_savings:
        most_savings = savings
        pers = person

 # print only the final result
 print(pers,"has the most savings at",most_savings)
```

You can also use the built in [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) function and specify a [lambda - function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/why-are-python-lambdas-useful) as keyfunction that evaluates the (key,**value**) part of the item into account when deciding whats max() ):

```
person, savings  = max( data.items(), key = lambda x:x[1])
print(person,"has the most savings at",savings)
```

Comment: Thanks Patrick for the swift help. Ive gotten the results that i want. But just for added knowledge, how can get the same result but this time round using **Def** and **return** function?

Comment: `def get_max_savings(savingdata): return  max( savingdata.items(), key = lambda x:x[1])` ? If you are unfamiliar with how functions works, read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) -you provide parameters to the functions, use those and return a result-if you return nothing the function returns `None` automatically (f.e. if your function just prints smth)